# RedShift - What happens if a user belongs to two groups with differ Queue

Tags: amazon-redshift

In RedShift, lets say I have a user called `user1`.

He belongs to 2 different groups.

1. Grp1
2. Grp2

Now, Im going to create a queue on WLM for `grp1` with 10 concurrencies and 80% of memory.

Then another queue for `grp2` with 1 concurrency and 10% memory.

After this, if the user `user1`connects to RedShift which queue will be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the order the queues are assigned.  Queue 6 evaluates before queue 7.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-queue-assignment-rules.html

user1 will be assigned to the queue (to which one of user1's groups are assigned) that evaluates first since both will match.

If you want user1 to be able to "choose" which queue they run in this can be done with the "query group" label but only if they don't match the earlier queue by group.  This way a user can "promote" their queries to an earlier queue based on setting a session variable.  If you have a user in 2 groups that match 2 queues their queries will always run in the queue that first matches. The flow chart in the link is very helpful.